# Android - issue with webview width in 4.4.4

Tags: android, webview

I have an app with webview. I test it in 4 versions of os - 4.2.2, 4.4.4, 5.1.0 and 6.0. It works good everywhere and looks like this

[image]

except 4.4.4, where width of webview is collapsed horizontally. It looks like this

[image]

In some answers there were advice of using `<meta name="viewport">` to fix the issue. I tried this line `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">` and it looks like this

[image]

Setting for webview that I use are following

```
webView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NORMAL);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
```

One other note. In activity I have a webView and 4 buttons. When activity loads in 4.4.4 it displays content of first string. It looks fine, just like in first screenshot. But when I start pressing buttons which changes content of webView, its content becomes like in screenshot two. Code for changing content is following

```
 body.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, resultArray[0].getBody(), "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
        }
    });
```

Any advices, how to fix the issue on 4.4.4 ?

Comment: If all the data are with html and if it is not url then you can use Html.fromHtml in textview.

Comment: it parses html tags ?

Comment: Yes it does parse Html tags

Answer (score 0):

Try below lines of code , it can be helpful for you:-

```
 WebView web_view = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.WEBVIEW);

  web_view.loadData("PUT YOURS DATA HERE", "text/html", "UTF-8");
  web_view.setBackgroundColor(0);
```

Or you can try another way to load the web content:-

```
YOUR_TEXTVIEW.setText(Html.fromHtml(PUT YOURS DATA HERE);
```

Comment: no, I tried this and it doesnt change content on buttons clicks

Comment: @AlexeyK ..Try second one..Did u try first above solution...What is problem are you facing??

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this one ?

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.noticiasWebView);
webView.setInitialScale(1);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
```

Hope this should works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Trust me I got the same thing a few months back and this code finally did it for me :

```
        WebView web=(WebView) vfrag.findViewById(R.id.webview);
        web.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        web.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        web.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        web.getSettings().setTextSize(WebSettings.TextSize.LARGEST);;    //This line is important
        web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

Comment: Then you would have to use a textView instead @AlexeyK